# Need Help with this smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I am newbie & trying smarty for Gravatar plugin like this.

```
<img src="{gravatar email="example@example.com"}">
```

But to get value of email I need to use {$client.email}

So My final code look like

```
<img src="{gravatar email="{$client.email}"}">
```

Which is not working.

Where I am going wrong ?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should rather be something like that:

```
<img src="{gravatar email=$client.email}">
```

However, its been a while since I last used smarty.

Be sure to also check the online documentation for smarty -> http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/